# Android - LeakCanary triggered - static helper method

Tags: android, static, leakcanary

I wrote myself a little helper class:

```
public enum NetworkUtils {
    ;

    public static boolean hasNetworkConnection(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager manager = getConnectivityManager(context);
        return manager != null
                && manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

    private static ConnectivityManager getConnectivityManager(Context context) {
        return (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

LeakCanary keeps telling me that I have an activity leak due to a reference to ConnectivityManager when I use that.

How to handle this situation? Is this a false positive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem myself: [Leak Canary Github issue](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/393)
The error can be prevented by using the application context:

```
(ConnectivityManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```